# How to set editable as true only for certain users in Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, restriction

I am using Fullcalendar for my project and I was wondering how it is possible to set event editable only for selected users.

I have tried doing this but it didn't seem to work

```
editable: function (event) {   
    if (event.createdby == "Admin") {
        return true 
    }
    else {
        return false 
    }
},
```

Comment: Where exactly in your code are setting the editable property?
Also, which language are you using for getting the events?

Comment: I'm writing the functions in the javascript and I'm using ASP .NET  MVC 5 C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `editable` option determines if the events can be dragged and resized. Enables/disables both at the same time.
I am not sure about the `event.createdby` call returns something like "Admin"(or any other user).

First you please check it by print it on `console.log()` or simply `alert(event.createdby);`. If this can show you **Admin** somehow, then it is all about the error in your code(like missing semicolon(;) after `return true` and `return false` in your code.

If you can take the `name`(or even `id`) of the 'selected user' to a variable like `createdby`, then it is just eazy as it is in the code below:

Change the code:

```
editable: function (event) {   
    if (event.createdby == "Admin") {
        return true 
    }
    else {
        return false 
    }
},
```

To this:

```
editable: (createdby == "Admin") ? true:false,
```

OR

```
editable: (createdid == 1) ? true:false,
```

Please note that `createdby` and `createdid` are javascript variables than contains selected user's name/id in your `caledar.js` file (as how you handle it in your project).

It is nothing about whether you use ASP, PHP, or MVC #... look how you can take uique users in the `calendar.js` file. There is a simple(best) way if you have the `id` in a hidden item in the content page.

That is by loading the value of the hidden field to the js variable like,

```
var createdid = $( "#idfield" ).val();
```

OR

```
var createdid = $( ".idfield" ).val();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thank You .. A great help indeed!

Can you please take a look into this as well..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228713/how-do-i-change-colors-for-overlapping-events-in-fullcalendar